# How to use SAX to get CDATA content

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, sax

I'm trying to parse a big XML file to get all outer XML tag content, something like this:

```
<string name="key"><![CDATA[Hey I'm a tag with & and other characters]]></string>
```

to get this:

```
<![CDATA[Hey I'm a tag with & and other characters]]>
```

Although, when I use Nokogiri's SAX XML parser I only get the text without CDATA and with characters escaped, like this:

```
Hey I\'m a tag with &amp; and other characters
```

This is my code:

```
  class IDCollector < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
    def initialize
    end

    def characters string
        puts string # this does not works, CDATA tag is not printed  
    end

    def cdata_block string
      puts string
      puts "<![CDATA[" + string + "]]>"
    end
  end
```

Is there any way to do this with Nokogiri SAX?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do: read or generate the CDATA block? You won't get `<![CDATA[Hey I'm a tag with & and other characters]]>` because it's a block, not a tag or element. `<![CDATA[` is effectively the tag but it's processed out and only its content is returned.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784183 might help. I can't duplicate getting the encoded result.

Comment: My final goal is to port some xml tags with their inner content to other files. Although, both file large and I have to use SAX or else I have an memory exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but this might help clear things up.

A `<![CDATA[...]]>` entry isn't a tag, it's a block, and is treated differently by the parser. When the block is encountered the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` are stripped off so you'll only see the string inside. See "[What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2784183)" for more information.

If you're trying to create a CDATA block in XML it can be done easily using:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(%(<string name="key"></string>))
doc.at('string') << Nokogiri::XML::CDATA.new(Nokogiri::XML::Document.new, "Hey I'm a tag with & and other characters")
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<string name=\"key\"><![CDATA[Hey I'm a tag with & and other characters]]></string>\n"
```

`<<` is just shorthand to create a child node.

Trying to use `inner_html` doesn't do what you want as it creates a text node as a child:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(%(<string name="key"></string>))
doc.at('string').inner_html = "Hey I'm a tag with & and other characters"
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<string name=\"key\">Hey I'm a tag with &amp; and other characters</string>\n"
doc.at('string').children.first.text # => "Hey I'm a tag with & and other characters"
doc.at('string').children.first.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
```

Using `inner_html` causes HTML encoding of the string to occur, which is the alternative way of embedding text that could include tags. Without the encoding or using `CDATA` the XML parsers could get confused about what is text versus what is a real tag. I've written RSS aggregators, and having to deal with incorrectly encoded embedded HTML in a feed is a pain.

Comment: Actually I prefer this (Nokogiri::XML::CDATA.new) to what I answer. Also, thanks for the described answer it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

After a while checking the documentation, I think this is only possible by building a new CDATA content with the help of Nokogiri, something like this:

```
  tmp = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
  value = tmp.create_cdata(value)
  r = doc.at_xpath(PATH_TO_REPLACE)
  r.inner_html = value
```